# How to retrieve decision id of IBM JSR 352 JSL

Tags: websphere-liberty, jsr352, java-batch

I run IBM JSR 352 batch job under Liberty Profile server. My JSL contains decision, e.g.

```
<decision id="condition_FTP" ref="ifConditionalStepDecider">
    <properties>
        <property name="IF_CONDITIONS" value='{"conditions":
            [
                "STEP2,=,0"
            ]}'/>
    </properties>
    <next on="SHOULD_EXECUTE" to="STEP03" />
    <next on="SHOULD_SKIP" to="intermediateStep_EMAILERR" />
</decision>
```

I have tried to retrieve the id of the decision from decider/batchlet but with no luck. It is not inside JobContext or StepContext. Does any of you guys know how I can retrieve it? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this with any specification API.   The way I would do this would be to create a new `property` under the decision properties and supply it.  This is inelegant because you have to repeat the name, but maybe more flexible ultimately, at least.

Comment: Thank you very much Scott. Yeah. This is something that I've thought about but just wanted to see if there is a more elegant way to do it.